# Defining a synonym for an environment name

Tags: listings, environments

I'm currently writing some assignments where I need to embed code fragments. I already found the `listings` package for that, which works fine.

My "problem" is, that I want to write`\begin{code}...\end{code}` rather than `\begin{lstlisting}...\end{lstlisting}`, which would be more intuitive (in my opinion).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: This is achievable, but not always recommended

Comment: How could I achieve it? What would speak against it?

Comment: One reason to speak against it: Some other package will have defined the `code` environment. Then there is the remote possibility that some other person will someday see your TeX and find it incomprehensible.

Comment: @HansWurst: (Nice nick name ;-)) Some environments are quite tricky to be wrapped using other names, especially the `lstlisting` environment with its verbatim content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `\lstnewenvironment` with an optional argument, which sets the `\lstset` options in the environment startup code. This definitely easier than to struggle with the special problem that the listings environment switches to verbatim and the necessity to inject a *string* `\end{lstlisting}` rather than the token `\end{lstlisting}`

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{code}[1][]{%
  \lstset{language={C},#1}%
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language={C}]
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World");
  return(0);
}
\end{lstlisting}


\begin{code}
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World");
  return(0);
}
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

Please compare that there is no difference for those two ways.

[image]

Comment: Please note, that `\lstnewenvironment` is meant for setup specific listings (i.e. certain styles, certain languages) rather than to used as a mere `synonym`